# How can I get babel to do ie compatibility with core-js

Tags: webpack, babeljs, core-js

I have this webpack code

```
...
rules: [
        {
            test: /(\.m?js?$)|(\.svelte$)/,
            exclude: /\bcore-js\b/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-env', {
                            targets: {
                                'ie':'11'
                            },
                            useBuiltIns: "usage",
                            corejs: 3
                        }]
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        // '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                        // '@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties'

                    ],
                    sourceType: 'unambiguous'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.svelte$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'svelte-loader',
                options: {
                    //emitCss: true,
                    hotReload: true
                }
            }
        },
...
```

And it works in chrome etc but in IE I get this error **SCRIPT5002: Function expected** in es.symbol.js
[image]

I can't quite see why that is or how to fix it, I thought core-js was going to solve that?

Comment: I would still like the answer but as a work-around for now I did the following: 1. Stop using core-js (by removing "useBuiltIns" and "corejs" 2. add es6-shim package and put import 'es6-shim'; at the top of my webpack entry file. This seems to work so for now I am simply not using core-js